# Is our [plot-device] malfunctioning?

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

The tag wiki for the [plot-device](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plot-device) tag says:

> An element introduced into a story, film, play etc. to advance the plot.

This is really *not* a good definition of a plot device. A plot device is a *narrative technique* used to advance the plot. Not every element of a story is a "plot device" even though almost every element of a story probably affects the plot in some way.

A plot device is really a "key" element of a story that *drives* the plot -- without which the plot wouldn't advance.

For example, in *Lord of the Rings*, the One Ring was a plot device, but Gimli's axe isn't.

Looking at the questions tagged [plot-device](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plot-device) a good number of them seem to be using it in the same way the previously-burninated [plot-explanation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plot-explanation) tag was used, i.e. "I didn't understand this part of the plot, what happened?". I think the overly broad tag guidance may be playing a role in this.

As it stands, with the current guidance, nearly *every* non-story-id question on this site could be tagged [plot-device](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plot-device). Should we try to make this better?

Comment: I love the title ROFL

Comment: Huh. I thought we'd already got rid of this one in the big Jan '16 tag cleanup.

Comment: so did I but we missed it. We got [plot-explanation] and [plot-inconsistency] and [plot-hole]; this one seems like an oversight, TBH, but I wanted to check :)

Answer (score 4):

Option 2: This tag is stupidly broad. We got rid of [plot-explanation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plot-explanation), get rid of this one.

Answer (score 4):

Option 3: Clarify the tag guidance and wiki, and clean up the tag where needed.

---

My suggestion for new tag guidance would be something like:

A **plot device** is a literary device (technique) that is introduced into a story to drive the plot forward. Plot devices can be actual objects (e.g. a MacGuffin) or merely a storytelling technique (e.g. a flashback). Use this tag to ask questions about the use of specific plot devices in sci-fi or fantasy works.

Comment: How useful would the tag be if we did this and left it?

Comment: Not sure; it's really more of a literary analysis type tag. Given our current policy on subjective analysis I think many of these questions would be off topic.

Comment: Arguably, a question like [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/158547/why-didnt-newt-scamander-just-release-the-thunderbird-the-moment-he-arrived-in) would apply; the Thunderbird is a literary device (a macguffin, essentially). But I dunno that the tag would actually help.

Comment: Yes, and we wouldn't be asking about plot-devices as a concept, we'd be asking about a specific plot-device, in which case it would probably have its own tag, or else not need one (IMO).

Comment: Wouldn't we then have to add the tag to hundreds of questions that don't have it, as well as probably remove it from a bunch that do?

Comment: Most likely, yes. So far of the 77 that are already tagged, very few of them qualify. I think the tag is better off dead, personally.

Comment: I'm upvoting this but frankly, i don't agree with this new description. As with other literary analysis type tags, it should be confined to questions ABOUT plot device as a literary technique, NOT all questions "about specific plot devices" as the text proposes. Questions about One Ring shouldn't have this tag in general - questions about use of One Ring in the plot **specifically as a device** should. Or, about plot devices in general

Comment: That is the idea I was trying to get across, actually. If we insist on keeping this tag I would definitely prefer better verbiage -- this was just a starting point

Answer (score -2):

Option 1: Leave this tag alone; it's not hurting anyone.

Comment: [Kill it, burn it with fire!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8T-YxNXoocw&feature=youtu.be&t=13s)